# Получаю ошибку error: [Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings]

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2, dagger

Использую Dagger. Когда в module добавляю @Single получаю следующую ошибку:

```
C:\Users\ghgh\AndroidStudioProjects\Viru\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\org\fasttokzal\viru\dagger\AppComponent.java:7: error: [Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] org.fasttokzal.viru.dagger.AppComponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:
public abstract interface AppComponent {
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Named("not_cache") @Singleton @Provides org.fasttokzal.viru.retrofit.Api org.fasttokzal.viru.dagger.TestModulGetApp.getApi()
```

Модуль вот:

```
@Module
class TestModulGetApp(private val app: Application) {
    @Provides
    //@Single если раскоментировать получу ошибку выше
    fun getApp() : Application {
        return app
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо у компонента в котором используется этот модуль, указать такой же Scope

```kotlin
@Single
@Component(modules = [TestModulGetApp::class])
interface AppComponent {
    ...
}
```

Компонент должен находится в том же Scope что и модули которые в нем используются
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#dagger-scopes
[image: Caution]

Comment: Cпс решил плюсик поставить, но проверить, пока не могу, даггер оказался сильно вредным и тяжелым для меня, короче я решил его из проекта убрать. Но может позже добавлю.